# Seeing if Two Strings are Anagrams [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, string, histogram, anagram

I am to write a program that will take 2 strings, put them into a function called "build_histogram" and build a int array that keeps count of how many times each letter appears in each string, then compare the arrays and if they are equal, then they are anagrams. The instructions state we are to ignore all symbols(ex. !, whitespaces, _, etc.) and it is not to be case sensitive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

void build_histogram(int letters[], string s) {

   for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      letters[s[i]]++;
   }
}


int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    int* histogram1[26];
    int* histogram2[26];

    cout << "Enter two strings." << endl;
    getline(cin, s1);
    getline(cin, s2);

    build_histogram(histogram1[26], s1);
    build_histogram(histogram2[26], s2);

   if(histogram1 != histogram2) {
      cout << "They are not anagrams." << endl;
   }
   else {
      cout << "They are anagrams!" << endl;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far, but no matter what strings I enter, I cannot get the program to print anything besides "Enter two strings."

**EDIT**

So this is my code now...it counts the number of characters correctly in each string, the only issue now is the "if else" statement at the bottom still doesn't recognize that the arrays are the same, also it's having a hard time when symbols like '!' are in the strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

void build_histogram(int letters[], string s) {

   for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char currLetter = s[i];
      currLetter = tolower(currLetter);

      int index = currLetter - 97;
      letters[index]++;
   }
}


int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    int histogram1[26] = {0};
    int histogram2[26] = {0};

    cout << "Enter two strings." << endl;
    getline(cin, s1);
    getline(cin, s2);

    build_histogram(histogram1, s1);
    build_histogram(histogram2, s2);


   if (histogram1 == histogram2) {
       cout << "They are not anagrams." << endl;
   } else {
       cout << "They are anagrams!" << endl;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The ASCII value of `A` is 64+1 = 65. The ASCII value of `a` is 64+32+1 = 97. How does that work with the `build_histogram` function?

Comment: sorry, we are to ignore case aswell. The function I am to write is supposed to just count how many times each letter appears and store it in the array..

example:

array[0] would store "a"
array[1] would store "b"

Comment: Reconsider `int * histogramX[26];` An array of pointers to `int` is not going to do you much good. In addition, initialising those array values is highly recommended. Hard to do any accurate counting if you don't know the starting value.

Comment: `histogram1 == histogram2` This is wrong way to compare arrays. Either you can compare corresponding values at indexes of both array or use `memcmp(histogram1, histogram2, sizeof(histogram1)*sizeof(int)) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Two strings are anagrams if they have the same length and one `std::is_permutation()`  of the other.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation

One could write a function to check if two strings are anagrams like this:

```
bool is_anagram(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {
    return s1.size() == s2.size() &&
        std::is_permutation(std::begin(s1), std::end(s1), 
            std::begin(s2), std::end(s2));
}
```

Comment: but my instructions say that the program is to ignore white spaces and symbols. (EXAMPLE input 1: "ign o r e! pu,c" input 2: "erognpcui"; although they are different lengths, and include different symbols, the program is to return that they are anagrams.)

Comment: then just remove all whitespace from both strings before checking.

Comment: There is a specific way our prof wants us to write it or we won't get credit...We haven't learned about removing whitespaces yet, so I don't think I will be able to do that and get full credit(our teacher is pretty lame and would rather us do it "his" way, even if there is a better way to do it.)

Answer (score -1):

This isnt your whole solution but it is definitely a start.

Your `letters[]` array only has indexes 0 through 25, therefore you'd want to convert your letters to correspond with 0-25.

Here is an easy way to do so:

```
void build_histogram(int* letters[], string s) {

   for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char currLetter = s[i];
      ///force letter to become lowercase
      currLetter = tolower(currLetter);

      ///make letter an ASCII value
      int index = currLetter - 97;//subtract 97 to get a range from 0 to 25
      letters[index]++;
   }
}
```

This implementation makes all letters into their lowercase forms.

Additionally, the number of instances of `'a'` would be stored in index 0, and `'z'` in index 25.

Hopefully this helps you go down the right track!

Comment: Thank goodness. I was starting to write something like this and I was hoping I was going in the right direction! Thank you!